# Get ranking within each group for r dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, ranking

I have a dataframe in R `dat` that contains the columns `Gene`, `Expression`, and `SampleID`. What I've done is sort `dat` such that it's grouped by `Gene` and arranged by descending `Expression` for each gene, using the following:

```
dat_sorted <- dat %>% select(Gene, Expression, SampleID) %>%
    group_by(Gene) %>% 
    arrange(Gene, desc(Expression))
```

What I now wish to do is add a `Rank` column to `dat_sorted` which would apply a rank within each `Gene` group based on the `Expression` value, such that, for a given gene, a given sample will have a higher rank if it's expression is higher.

Here's an example of what the outcome should look like:

```
Gene                Expression      Sample      Rank
ENSG00000000003     2.81561500      HSB671      1
ENSG00000000003     2.79336700      HSB431      2
ENSG00000000003     2.40009100      HSB618      3
ENSG00000000938     1.75148448      HSB671      1
ENSG00000000938     1.52182467      HSB670      2
ENSG00000000938     0.83478860      HSB414      3
ENSG00000000938     0.62174432      HSB459      4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like people forgot about your question. Hope this doesn't come too late ^^

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Gene) %>% mutate(Rank = dense_rank(desc(Expression)))

> df
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   Gene [2]
  Gene            Expression Sample  Rank
  <chr>                <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1 ENSG00000000003      2.82  HSB671     1
2 ENSG00000000003      2.79  HSB431     2
3 ENSG00000000003      2.40  HSB618     3
4 ENSG00000000938      1.75  HSB671     1
5 ENSG00000000938      1.52  HSB670     2
6 ENSG00000000938      0.835 HSB414     3
7 ENSG00000000938      0.622 HSB459     4
```

Or with base R:

```
df$Rank <- ave(-df$Expression, df$Gene, FUN = rank)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a row number column, since the dataframe is already sorted in descending order. So, the highest Rank will be on top and lowest on bottom. In that case, just add a sequence number column as Rank. Like below:

```
   dat_sorted$Rank <- seq.int(nrow(dat_sorted))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I think that's on the right track but that method doesn't take into account the different genes. In my question above, I grouped the dataframe by gene, so I'm trying to get the ranking to restart for each gene if that makes sense.